# How To Solve Bootstrap Grid Issue On mobile?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im editing a description on Ebay listing Where no scripting is allowed. 
The ebay description is embedded within the ebay template.

I've discovered that my #portfolio doesn't display correctly on [mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sa5Do.png)!

On the [desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbN47.png) it works absolutely fine as they are col-lg-3. On mobile ive used col-xs-6 as I would like a 2 x 2 grid. 
The problem is that the last column gets dragged into another row. 
See mobile image above displaying my issue.

Would anyone be able to teach me a new css trick that stops the last column getting sucked into a new row?

```
<div id="portfolio" class="container-fluid text-center ">
    <h2><font color="#ce2065">the shills black mask</font><br><font size="1">&nbsp;</font></h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img src="http://justbeauty-uk.s3.amazonaws.com/shillspoint1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail img-circle margin" alt="Image" style="text-align: center; width: 60%;">
            <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="line-height: 1.8;">The latest trend in skincare.&nbsp;</span>Proven results with the word’s best selling black mask - loved by beauty bloggers, as seen on YouTube</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img src="http://justbeauty-uk.s3.amazonaws.com/shillspoint2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail img-circle margin" alt="Image" style="text-align: center; width: 60%;">
            <p><span style="line-height: 1.8;">Activated charcoal quickly and effectively pulls blackheads from the root and aids skin regeneration. Promotes healthy skin too!</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img src="http://justbeauty-uk.s3.amazonaws.com/shillspoint3.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail img-circle margin" style="text-align: center; width: 60%;">
            <p><span style="line-height: 1.8;">Brightening naturally-derived ingredients calendula, rosemary and grapefruit help restore a plump, youthful complexion.</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img src="http://justbeauty-uk.s3.amazonaws.com/shillspoint2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail img-circle margin" style="text-align: center; width: 60%;" alt="Image">
            <p><span style="line-height: 1.8;">Deeply penetrates the pores to remove acne-causing oil, which is also the main cause of acne outbreaks. Three more words.</span></p>
            <p>
                <br>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*Portfolio items*/


    #portfolio .portfolio-item {
        margin: 0 0 15px;
        right: 0;
        border: 1px outset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    }

    #portfolio .portfolio-item:hover {
        transition: 0.5s;
        box-shadow: 5px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    }

    #portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        max-width: 400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all ease .5s;
        -webkit-transition: all ease .5s;
        -moz-transition: all ease .5s,
    }

    #portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover:hover {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    #portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover .portfolio-hover-content {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -12px;
        color: #fff;
    }

    #portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover .portfolio-hover-content i {
        margin-top: -12px;
    }

    #portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover .portfolio-hover-content h3,
    #portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover .portfolio-hover-content h4 {
        margin: 0;
    }

    #portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-caption {
        max-width: 400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        text-align: center;
        padding: 25px;
    }

    #portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-caption h4 {
        color: #fff;
        text-transform: none;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-caption p {
        font-family: "Droid Serif", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-style: italic;
        font-size: 13px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #portfolio * {
        z-index: 2;
    }

    @media (min-width:767px) {
        #portfolio .portfolio-item {
            margin: 0 0 30px;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent objects from jumping You need to use `clearfix` wich is visible for xs viewports only.
It looks like:

```
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
```

So here is a resulting code:

```
<div id="portfolio" class="container-fluid text-center ">
    <h2><font color="#ce2065">the shills black mask</font><br><font size="1">&nbsp;</font></h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img src="http://justbeauty-uk.s3.amazonaws.com/shillspoint1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail img-circle margin" alt="Image" style="text-align: center; width: 60%;">
            <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="line-height: 1.8;">The latest trend in skincare.&nbsp;</span>Proven results with the word’s best selling black mask - loved by beauty bloggers, as seen on YouTube</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img src="http://justbeauty-uk.s3.amazonaws.com/shillspoint2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail img-circle margin" alt="Image" style="text-align: center; width: 60%;">
            <p><span style="line-height: 1.8;">Activated charcoal quickly and effectively pulls blackheads from the root and aids skin regeneration. Promotes healthy skin too!</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img src="http://justbeauty-uk.s3.amazonaws.com/shillspoint3.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail img-circle margin" style="text-align: center; width: 60%;">
            <p><span style="line-height: 1.8;">Brightening naturally-derived ingredients calendula, rosemary and grapefruit help restore a plump, youthful complexion.</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img src="http://justbeauty-uk.s3.amazonaws.com/shillspoint2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail img-circle margin" style="text-align: center; width: 60%;" alt="Image">
            <p><span style="line-height: 1.8;">Deeply penetrates the pores to remove acne-causing oil, which is also the main cause of acne outbreaks. Three more words.</span></p>
            <p>
                <br>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You so much, it worked. Ill look into the docs for further explanation

Comment: The last column gets dragged into another row not because a mobile viewport. It happens when height of 1st card exceeds height of 2nd one. So 3rd element behaves as a "bubble" and pushes 4th one to the next row.